# What instruments and techniques measured Mars' atmospheric D/H ratio which suggests (all of) it's water didn't evaporate after all?

Tags: mars, atmosphere, chemistry, measurement, spectroscopy

The Time article [Mars Has Much More Water Than Previously Known—But There's a Catch](https://time.com/5947142/water-on-mars/) says:

> The greater weight of deuterium causes it to behave differently in the Martian atmosphere. While free hydrogen atoms that were once part of a water molecule escape into space, free deuterium weighs enough to hang around in the air. Over time, as more and more hydrogen drifts away from the planet and more and more deuterium stays behind, the ratio of deuterium to hydrogen (D/H) slowly grows.
>
> “The loss of hydrogen is a sort of constant removal,” says Eva Lingh Scheller, Caltech PhD candidate and the lead author of the paper. “Removing it from the total volume is going to give you a larger D/H ratio.”
>
> **But there’s a problem with common measures of Mars’s D/H ratio, Scheller and her colleagues found. Using atmospheric observations by NASA’s MAVEN Mars satellite and the European Space Agency’s Mars Express craft, they concluded that the current ratio is simply too low.** If all of Mars’s water had escaped to space, taking its free hydrogen atoms with it, there would be much more deuterium in the modern day Martian sky relative to the remaining free hydrogen—by some measures, more than twice as much. That means that much of the planet’s water never escaped, and the only other place it could have gone was into the soil and rocks—especially into clay, the most abundant mineral on Mars.

That Mars' water may not have all evaporated but instead "gone underground" is pretty important, so I'd like to ask these

**Questions:**

1. Which instruments on MAVEN and Mars Express measured the D/H ratio in Mars' atmosphere?
2. What techniques were used to separately detect the amounts of these two isotopes of hydrogen? Were wavelengths involved? Diffraction gratings? Etalons? Microwaves? Mass Spectrometers?

Potentially helpful:

- Science: E. L. Scheller et al. (2021) [Long-term drying of Mars by sequestration of ocean-scale volumes of water in the crust](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/early/2021/03/15/science.abc7717) (open access at [authors.library.caltech.edu](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/108469/9/nihms-1730612.pdf))

Comment: I did not quite understand the initial suggestion: "That Mars' water may not have all evaporated but instead "gone underground". 

If Earth is a valid comparison to Mars, then, "gone underground" needs to be clarified.



On Earth there is more water locked in rocks than in the surface oceans. "The high water storage capacity of minerals in Earth’s mantle transition zone (410- to 660-kilometer depth) implies the possibility of a deep H2O reservoir" https://www.science.org/doi/abs/10.1126/science.1253358

Comment: On the other hand, 

Distribution of water on Earth

Glaciers and other ice: 2.15 percent
 ------------- 
Groundwater: 0.61 percent

Comment: In the primordial Mars atmosphere there was a lot of evaporation !  Didn't you mean escape to space instead of evaporation ?  And the article that you  cited says that *much* of the water never escaped, not *all of it.*

Comment: @Cornelis that might be what I meant, but maybe not. I need to have my morning coffee first; after two or three brain cells kick-in I'll dig back into this (written three years ago). I might have just been referring to where the surface liquid water went - did it evaporate into the atmosphere or go underground, and might not have been asking what happened to the vapor subsequent to evaporation. I'm not sure the "escape to space" step is part of what I'm asking about

Comment: my two cents:  a lot of uhoh's questions have some loose/colloquial phrasing or whatever, but it's almost always clear in context (as it is here, since the source quote is right next to it).  Rephrasing that short paragraph might be "more correct" but it won't make the question more clear or more answerable, because it was already clear and answerable.  I wouldn't change it.

Comment: @Cornelis: Atmospheric escape to space is often loosely referred to as evaporation.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape The definition of evaporation is  "the process of a *liquid* converting to the *gaseous* state". On Mars, evaporation would be from the surface into the atmosphere, not directly into space. Give us only one example of a scientific article in which your assertion is showed.

Comment: @ErinAnne  "water didn't *evaporate*" is just a wrong phrasing in this context, it should be "water didn't *escape to space*. Also, from the abstract: "Between 30 and 99% of martian water was sequestered through crustal hydration", so it is more likely that 2/3 was sequestered and 1/3 of the water escaped to space , certainly not that *all of it* did not evaporate or escaped to space.

Comment: @ErinAnne And if with "evaporate" in the text of the question is meant "escape to space", then it's not water evaporating, but **deuterium**.

Comment: @Cornelis okay let's put this to rest please, or move it to chat. Please reread the end of my question. "That means that much of the planet’s water never escaped, and the only other place it could have gone was into the soil and rocks." My question is about where the surface water went - did it all evaporate to the atmosphere or go underground. The question isn't about what happens *post evaporation* it's only about *how much evaporated*.

Comment: @Cornelis What, do you want me to quote the entire atmospheric escape literature at you? Here we go, https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016ApJ...817..107O/abstract e.g. Photoevaporation, a process via which cold gas is heated and accelerated to escape velocity is ubiquitous in protoplanetary discs and hot exoplanets.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape You're right, *photoevaporation*  is totally different from just *evaporation* by the warming of water.

Comment: @uhoh  It's  the use of the word "evaporate" in the *title* of your question that I question.  *Evaporation and subsequent condensation* were part of the daily water cycle on Mars. It was *not evaporation* that changed the D/H ratio, it was the escape of hydrogen from the *dissociation* of water into space.

Comment: @Cornelis Again, this question is not about what you want to talk about, it's about where the surface water disappeared to. My question mentions a D/H ratio measurement yes, but it does not ask about the thing you keep mentioning. This is the last time I'll say "okay let's put this to rest please, or move it to chat". I'll just flag for moderator attention next time.

Comment: @uhoh  I don't want to hide my comments from the public and I can't help it that you obviously don't want to understand what I'm writing.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have access to the Science paper in question (would have to register, boo, that ain't open) so I don't see what Scheller et al cited for their D/H sources (the abstract makes it look like the data collection is not part of their work, only simulation to explain it), but two papers make it look like the instrument on MAVEN must be IUVS, the [Imaging Ultraviolet Spectrograph](https://lasp.colorado.edu/home/maven/science/instrument-package/iuvs/), looking for the [Lyman-alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyman-alpha_line) brightness of either isotope:

- [Estimate of the D/H Ratio in the Martian Upper Atmosphere from the Low Spectral Resolution Mode of MAVEN/IUVS](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/2020JE006814)

  > In this study, we use models to estimate the D/H ratio at 80 and 200 km from low resolution Lyman-α limb profiles measured by the Imaging Ultraviolet Spectrograph aboard the Mars Atmosphere and Volatile EvolutioN
- [Variability of D and H in the Martian upper atmosphere
  observed with the MAVEN IUVS echelle channel](https://lasp.colorado.edu/home/maven/files/2017/02/Variability-of-D-and-H-in-the-Martian-Upper-Atmosphere-Observed-with-the-MAVEN-IUVS-Echelle-Channel.pdf)

  > The MAVEN IUVS instrument contains an echelle spectrograph channel designed to measure D
  > and H Ly α emissions from the upper atmosphere of Mars. This channel has successfully recorded both
  > emissions, which are produced by resonant scattering of solar emission, over the course of most of a martian
  > year.

The IUVS page above also links to [a presentation including requirements and details of the instrument](https://lasp.colorado.edu/home/maven/files/2012/12/8-IUVS-Schneider.pdf) which is very detailed, including slides like
[image: a Powerpoint slide explains the "spectral resolution requirement flows from need to minimize intensity in wings of the bright H Lyman alpha line at the position of D Lyman alpha" with associated counts per hour vs. wavelength graph]

Looking for Mars Express instruments with objectives to measure the D/H ratio brought me to the [Planetary Fourier Spectrometer for Mars Express](https://sci.esa.int/documents/33745/35957/1567254800595-FormiWeb.pdf) but I'm not readily finding another supporting source (except good indications that the Planetary Fourier Spectrometer actually flew, not just on Mars Express but also Venus Express as well).  Unsurprisingly, spectroscopy also appears to be the proposed D/H ratio measurement method with this instrument:

> The 1.87 μm band appears to be the most convenient for H 2O detection, as it is almost free of overlap with the CO2 bands. However, the 2.7 μm band will be used to make the H 2O abundance determination more accurate
> ...
> PFS also provides an additional opportunity for detection of the 3.7 μm HDO band. It was observed in the martian spectrum by Owen et al. (1988) and the D/H ratio was found to be considerably higher than on Earth (about 6 times). PFS could provide a new, independent determination of this ratio.

The same paper has an extremely detailed Instrument Description section.

Comment: wow, it's looking like [two-for-two](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61946/12102)! :-) btw I don't know why I labeled it as open access to the paper in Science (linked at the end of my question), but I did manage to find what seems to be an open access copy now, and updated the question with the link (at the bottom of the post).

Comment: @uhoh without looking back, I think Science themselves labeled it open, since it was available via free registration instead of charging a fee.  Their bad, not yours

Comment: Thank you for this answer. As far as I understand, the limb and nadir observation modes both have the possibility of probing the bulk D/H ratio in the atmosphere, not just a high-altitude layer, which might have a different value. Is this correct, according to your reading of the observation modes?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I regret to say that I do not understand these papers well enough to answer a question like that.  Remote sensing is not my specialty.

Comment: @uhoh BTW, it wasn't the D/H ratio which suggests most Mars' water *didn't* escape to space, it was a new model in the paper that simulated volcanic degassing, atmospheric escape and crustal hydration that lead the authors to this conclusion. Before this paper, with the same D/H ratio from the instruments, the long-accepted view was that most of Mars' water *did* escape to space.